# Multiple addons found by Blender but only one is in folder

Tags: add-on, error, makehuman

I have installed the MakeClothes addon, but the "Multiple Add-ons with the same name found" error pops up. It is only in one folder with one copy of each file. Everytime I try to fix it, the add on disapears. How do I fix that?